# Integrating Araxis Merge 2010 with Visual Studio 2010 and TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, araxis

I'm trying to get Araxis Merge 2010 integration with Visual Studio working and am coming up against a brick wall with the arguments you should pass to Merge.exe.

According to [their documentation](http://www.araxis.com/merge/scm_integration.html#VisualStudioTeamFoundation) it arguments should be:

`/wait /swap /a3 /3 /title1:%6 /title2:%7 /title3:%8 %1 %2 %3 %4`

However this doesn't seem to work, does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

When doing a merge the tool pops up, but the head says, /wait and /swap could not be found, it's almost as if it's interpreting the flags as the files to compare.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works fine for me - but there is a gotcha.

For merges, you must **not** set the .exe to "merge.exe" as sounds obvious, but to **"compare.exe"**! It's explained better here on the [original post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) that they took those settings from.

(Hopefully that's what tripped you up)

Comment: @jonnii: it's an easy mistake to make - it's totally unintuitive, and they haven't mentioned it in the official documentation.